# How to use Guice bindings in Gin module for PlayN?

Tags: gwt, guice, playn, gwt-gin

Imagine you have a PlayN game which uses Guice bindings in its core project:

```
/* PlayN core Guice module */
public class MyGameModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Title.class).to("My game title");
        // Other bindings...
    }

}
```

What if you want to use those **same bindings**, but on your GWT project of the game (with Gin)?

In the Java project it's as easy as it gets:

```
/* PlayN Java Guice module */
public class MyGameModuleJava extends MyGameModule {

    // **OK**: no manual intervention required.

}
```

Can this be achieved without having to manually copy-paste the Guice module's configure method to the Gin module? For example, this works as a workaround, but is not what I'd prefer to do:

```
/* PlayN GWT Gin module */
public class MyGameModuleHtml extends AbstractGinModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // **NOK**: copy-paste the Guice module, as shown below.
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Title.class).to("My game title");
        // Other bindings...
    }

}
```

It works, but it's not pretty to say the least.

**Bottom line**: I want to use **same bindings** across all PlayN projects.

### Solution

So what I did is use the `GinModuleAdapter` in my Java main, based on the answer:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GinModuleAdapter(new MyGameModuleHtml()));
```

This way I could remove the Guice bindings in the core classes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to do it in reverse. E.g. bindings will be defined in GWT project and used in Guice via `GinModuleAdapter` (it will allow you to create Guice module from Gin module)